# send a body value from a service to BAM

Tags: web-services, xpath, wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I have difficulties to understand how to log a XML XPath property in a webservice with WSO2 BAM.
Indeed I want to basically take a subset of the payload returned by my backend and send this subset to WSO2 BAM
How to do it ? 
Tks
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Property mediator in ESB to capture the product price using xpath in the message body and set it as a property in Message Context of ESB. Next to the Property mediator       add the BAM mediator to ESB sequence and capture the property in the Message Context as shown in [1]. In the document it has shown how to capture the System Date. Similarly you can capture the product price property. (e.g., get-property('product_price'))

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator